# UIPageViewController - remove white margins?

Tags: ios, border, uipageviewcontroller

So views of the controllers displayed one by one by the UIPageViewController, do not occupy the whole view of UIPageViewController. On the screen, they are flanked by these white borders (top, right, bottom, left).

How do get rid of these borders? I want these views to occupy all available space.
Thanks

Comment: There is no such setting on UIPageViewController.  You are setting that behavior yourself.  Most likely because you copied and pasted code from somewhere.  Show us the code where you are creating the UIPageViewController.

Comment: @johnny Mac - paste your code..

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, I was using this sample code Apple provides, the borders resulted from the code. Thanks guys.